# How to use file.seek() inside a python loop?

Tags: python, file

below is my simple code snippet where I want the program to read the file from the top again, in case a function is pleased:

```
wordlist = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
words = wordlist.read().splitlines()
for word in words:
    if ...():
        wordlist.seek(0) #starting reading the file from the top again
        words = wordlist.read().splitlines()
        for word in words:
            if ...():
               #do sth else and so on
```

Any idea how to use file.seek() correctly, because when executed, the program continues to read the wordlist without going again to the start.

Comment: Can you provide the output vs expected output

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem in this case. ``words = wordlist.read().splitlines()`` is redundant, since the file content cannot change in this scenario. So just use ``words`` again. And do not use the variable name ``word`` in your nested ``for`` loop, it's already used by the outer loop.

Comment: Could not reproduce. `seek` working as expected for me.

Comment: Also, your outer list is already using a fixed iterator based on `words`, so changing the value of `words` inside the loop won't affect the outermost iteration.